# $n in PHP preg_replace

Tags: php

I saw some code from [this website](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=36992):

```
function link($text){
    return preg_replace('@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
```

What do `$0` and `$1` mean? Are they regular variables, or do they have special meaning?

Comment: "php $0" turns out dozens of results. Do they not show what you're interested with?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Where do you see how?

Comment: where did you see it..? could you show some code sample..?

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888417/what-does-the-124-mean-in-this-preg-replace

Comment: Is this in the context of regular expressions perhaps?

Comment: I saw it here: http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=36992

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$0` or `$1` if used for `preg_replace` function;

```
preg_replace ($pattern , $replacement , $subject)
```

`replacement` may contain references of the form \n or (since PHP 4.0.4) $n, with the latter form being the preferred one. Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th parenthesized pattern. n can be from 0 to 99, and \0 or $0 refers to the text matched by the whole pattern.

from php doc: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

In the sample URL provided, $1 refers to the first captured sub-pattern in the preg_replace.  Refer to the documentation at: https://www.php.net/preg_replace

> Every such reference will be replaced by the text captured by the n'th
> parenthesized pattern. n can be from 0 to 99, and \0 or $0 refers to
> the text matched by the whole pattern. Opening parentheses are counted
> from left to right (starting from 1) to obtain the number of the
> capturing subpattern.